# Dual Boot Missing for Mint Linux

Tags: linux-mint, dual-boot, grub

I have been installed Mint Linux 19.1 alongside my Windows 10. After installation I could't find a Grub Menu on Boot. It directly goes to Mint Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Boot-Repair, I've had great luck with it in the past

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

After it opens try the Recommended repair

Answer (score 1):

Before going for `boot-repair`, you should try `update-grub` first.

But first things first, you should see if you can see all your OSes in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.